# how to read the string from a table which are seperated by commas using mysql

Tags: java, mysql, string

I have a requirement to read the string which is separated by commas and it should be set to JavaBean.the table is like this.

```
+---------+-------------------------------------+--------------+
| crsd_id | crsd_crsm_id                        | crsd_lgnm_id |
+---------+-------------------------------------+--------------+
|       3 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13       | 2,3          |
|       6 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 | 3            |
|       7 | 14,15                               | 2,3,4,5      |
+---------+-------------------------------------+--------------+
```

I have to read the first row (`crsd_crsm_id`) one by one and it should set to JavaBean like this

```
courseBean.setCRSD_CRSM_ID(courseListSet.getString(2));
```

can anyone help me how to do it.

Comment: does this help u [GROUP CONCAT] ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 1):

Construct your courseListSet with the crsd_crsm_id field as parameter and then 
internally split it up via `String.split()` and offer it for reading

```
public class CrsdCrsmId {

  private String[] courses;

  public CrsdCrsmId(String in) {
      courses = in.split(",");
  }

  public String getCourse(int i) {
     // TODO check if index i exists
     return courses[i];
  }
...
}
```

you can then do

```
String val = mysqldb.getVal();
CrsdCrsmId c = new CrsdCrsmId(val);
String course5 = c.getCourse(5);
```

Comment: thak you rupp for your response.

Comment: hi rupp,i am using collection .I am using ArrayList .Finally i am getting the result from CourseBean and keeping in collection.can u help me